# Работа с числами

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Объясню на примере: 
Пользователь передает через форму 2 числа: 2000 и 1000.
У скрипта задача - уменьшить число, как минимум, до 1000, если оно больше, при этом пропорционально должно уменьшиться и второе число.
Т.е. в итоге должно получить 1000 и 500.
Примечание: первое число не обязательно должно быть больше второго.

В принципе, задача простая, но не могу додуматься, как такое реализовать?

p.s. Думаю, это как-то связано с циклами, но хотелось бы увидеть мнение других программистов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем циклы?

```
$maxval = max($val1, $val2)
if ($maxval > 1000)
{
    $coeff = 1000.0 / $maxval;
    $val1 *= $coeff;
    $val2 *= $coeff;
}
```

Comment: Думал, что, возможно, стоит через цикл делить эти 2 числа до тех пор, пока результат не устроит...) Ваш скрипт проще получился - спасибо! :)

Comment: каким циклом? зачем у вас уже условие не больше тысячи, то есть перерасчет будет сделан таким образом что большее число станет тысячей а второе пропорционально уменьшиться

Comment: @nick777: пожалуйста!